# how does this work when the column which is there in select but not there in group

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

This column DATE_FORMAT(date, "%b") AS month which is there in select but not there in group by clause . Instead it has a different column but still it works. How does this work?

My understanding is the column which is there in select clause has to be there in the group by clause.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, "%b") AS month, SUM(total_price) as total
FROM cart
WHERE date <= NOW() and date >= Date_add(Now(),interval - 12 month)
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, "%m-%Y"
```

Comment: can provide `cart` table sample data?

Comment: You should read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html mysql will allow this but you may not get the 'correct' result.

Answer (score 0):

You query is not allowed in Standard SQL.  Nor is it allowed in recent versions of MySQL using the default settings.  If you have an older version, you can have the query rejected by setting [only_full_group_by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by).

The specific error is actually pretty clear:

> Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'db_1133225228.cart.date' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

See [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bd159071b8e2178a5b8b88d2ff5e0665).

As a general rule, the unaggregated `SELECT` expressions need to be in the `GROUP BY`.  (The one exception is basically when the `GROUP BY` contains a primary key; then any column can be used.)

What happens in older versions of MySQL or when `only_full_group_by` is not set correctly?  In that case, an *arbitrary* value from the group is chosen for the value.  This value *could* change on different runs of the query (although in practice the value is pretty stable).

However, my advice is to use `only_full_group_by` to write queries that are consistent with the standard and pretty much all other databases in this respect.